# substr() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, массивы

работаю с массивом и использую функцию substr, где то есть ошибка но не понимаю где, помогите пожалуйста.

```
if(in_array('OK',$exp))
      {
          $oneKey=array_search('OK', $exp);
          $InfNap[]= substr($exp[1],1);
          $TrasType[]=$exp[$oneKey+2];
          $Ses[]=$exp[$oneKey-3];
          $Ses = substr($Ses, 0,-2);
          $index++;
      }
```

Comment: что в $exp[1]  и в $Ses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Ses[] = $exp[$oneKey-3]; <- $Ses[] объявлена массивом
$Ses = substr($Ses, 0,-2); <- 1м аргументом ожидается строка, но подставлен массив.
```

Comment: да вы правы,  $Ses[]=$exp[$oneKey-3]; здесь убрал [] и все заработало, спасибо за помощь